# does return statement actually return the value or store it in function?

Tags: c, function, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b)
{ return a+b;}

int main()
{
 printf("%d\n",add(7,9));
 return 0;
}
```

in above code,
Is "add(int, int)" variable also? 
because we can print it like variable.

In add function,
Does return statement stores the value (a+b) to "(*add) (int, int)" OR it just return the value whenever function is called?

If function stores the return value then how to find the memory location at which return value is stored?

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
 printf("%d\n",add(7,9));
```

the argument to the conversion specifier `%d` is the value of the *expression* `add(7,9)`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.2

> If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning an
>   object type, the function call expression has the same type as that object type, and has the
>   value determined as specified in 6.8.6.4.[...]

In chapter 6.8.6.4, we can see,

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
>   returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression.

Now, `add(7,9)` being a function call (*function call
expression*), the function will get called and the return value of the function will be considered as the argument.

So, no, `"add(int, int)"` is not a variable.

Comment: Your C compiler will have an option to dump the actual machine code assembly instructions to a file. If you enable this then open the file in an editor you will see that values returned from functions are typically passed back to the calling function in a processor register. This can not have an address because it is not memory.

Answer (score 1):

In C exist the concept of Lvalue and Rvalue.
An Lvalue is by definition an object that persists beyond a single expression, or more simply a value that points to a storage location, potentially allowing new values to be assigned to it.
All others are Rvalues, a temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that uses it.
In your case the function `int add(int a, int b)` returns an Rvalue that exists and can be used only inside the expression where it is used. In your case the `printf()`.
All variables are instead Lvalues, so using an assignment expression as:

```
int result = add(4, 5);
```

Saves the Rvalue returned from call to `add()` into the variabble result, that is an Lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Frankie's answer, an lvalue is something that can be assigned to.  That means it has an address.  This is in contrast to a rvalue, which does not exist beyond the expression it is used in and therefore does not have an address.

Because the return value of a function is an rvalue, it does not have an address.  So to answer your question, when you `return` it basically just returns the value to whatever expression it was called from and does not store it anywhere.